# Existe passagem de parâmetro em uma trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, trigger

Eu tenho duas tabelas, uma com as sessões e outra com as atividades. Dentro da tabela atividades eu tenho dois campos, disponível e vendível e dentro de sessão eu tenho vagas.

Gostaria de pegar o id da sessão pra poder fazer o update no campo vendível, quando zerasse as vagas que o campo atividade.vendível fizesse update para 0.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER atualizarStatus
AFTER UPDATE ON sessao
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (sessao.vagas = 0) THEN
UPDATE atividade SET vendivel = 0 WHERE id = $id;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Essa não é a ideia das triggers, talvez você queira executar uma procedure. Os únicos "parâmetros"  em uma trigger são as linhas novas `new.*` e antigas `old.*`

Comment: Uma procedure consegue fazer o que eu quero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua tentativa estava muito perto de atingir o objectivo. Tente assim:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER atualizarStatus
   AFTER UPDATE ON sessao 
     FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF NEW.vagas = 0 THEN
      UPDATE atividade SET vendivel = 0 WHERE id = NEW.id;
   END IF;
END;
```

No trigger, as palavras reservadas NEW e OLD permitem acesso às colunas dos registos que foram afectados pela instrução que despoletou o trigger. Neste caso pode usar NEW para aceder ao estado do registo após o UPDATE.